# Cosa significa "quinta" in questo testo?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il giardino dei Finzi-Contini*, di Giorgio Bassani, ho letto:

> Smontai dalla bicicletta, restando a guardare per un attimo la soglia deserta. 
>   Tagliata di traverso nella nera **quinta** del battente di sinistra rimasto chiuso, 
>   intravedevo una piccola, ripida scala ricoperta da una guida rossa: d'un rosso acceso, 
>   scarlatto, sanguigno. Ad ogni gradino una sbarra d'ottone, lustra e scintillante come se fosse d'oro.

Non capisco qual è il significato di "quinta" in questo brano. Ho cercato questo vocabolo in parecchi dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Mi potreste spiegare cosa vuol dire "quinta" nel passaggio precedente?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indica in questo caso il pannello di legno del portone di ingresso; il significato viene preso dal teatro (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinta_(teatro)) dove la quinta è un pannello mobile di solito di stoffa (ma può essere anche di legno) che serve a delimitare la scena; il pannello della porta - dal brano immagino che sia un portone a due ante - in questo caso agisce come quinta nel senso che nasconde quello che c'è dietro (la scala intravista dal narratore).